# reactstrap <Navbar> fixed on top

Tags: reactstrap

I'm using reactstap and try to implement a navbar being fixed, which works partially, since the navbar is fixed, but the very next component moves to the top (behind the navbar). If the fixed attribute is not set, the content appears correctly below the navbar.

```
<Navbar className="bg-dark" color="dark" fixed="top" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a margin or padding to the top of the body to move it down to compensate for the height of your navbar.

Add to your stylesheet:

```
body {
  padding-top: 45px;
}
```

or add it to your `body` or `main` tag as an inline style.